# "The C++ Programming Language 4ed." [Stroustrup 2013] concrete classes: "if the representation changes significantly...user must recompile"?

Tags: c++

B. Stroustrup writes about concrete classes:

> The representation can be private...and accessible only through the member functions, but it is present. **Therefore, if the representation changes in any significant way, a user must recompile.** This is the price to pay for having concrete types behave exactly like built-in types.

I am a little confused by this, because I don't understand how the representation of a concrete class can change during run-time. Another way I can ask the question would be: how can I change the representation of a concrete class "insignificantly" post-compilation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not talking about things happening at run-time, it is about source code evolution.

It means, if you change the source code of the class in a significant way, then you lose binary compatibility, so existing code using that class will also need to be recompiled.

Answer (score 0):

For example if you change your class declaration by moving private variables to public, those variables can access without using member functions. In such a scenario, you need to recompile the code.  The quoted para is not trying to explain  about 'after post compilation' run time scenario instead it is meant for 'post compilation' class redesign scenario.